# CS50 pset6, searching for matching DNA values

Tags: python, function, for-loop, nested, cs50

I have gotten to the final stage of the problem so I believe. My code successfully reads the csv and txt files, and the lists I created seem to accurately store this data (I tried print statements throughout to check all my values and they were correct), yet the program never returns a person's name, just "No match" when executed. I reckon from this, my issue is in the final, nested for loop in main(). Any help/tips appreciated! Thanks

```
import csv
import sys


def main():

    # Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: ./dna.py [FILE.csv] [FILE.txt]")
        return


    # Create list of headers to contain headers[0] = name, headers[1] = 'AGATC'... etc
    # Create list of rows to contain one row for each person's name and STR values

    headers = []
    rows = []
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for i in range(len(reader.fieldnames)):
            headers.append(reader.fieldnames[i])

        for row in reader:
            rows.append(row)

    # Can now reference STR of a specific person by rows[i][headers[str]], where 'i' is a person's row number, and 'str' is the required STR's value

    # Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as txtfile:
        sequence = txtfile.read()


    # Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    mostRepeats = []
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        mostRepeats.append(longest_match(sequence, headers[i]))


    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for j in range(len(headers)):
            if rows[i][headers[j]] == mostRepeats[j]:
                print(rows[i]['name'])
                return


    print("No match")
    return


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Seems to me you could easily debug this with a debugger, or even printing what the values are that you are about to compare in the `if rows[i][headers[j]] == mostRepeats[j]:` statement.

Comment: You need to skip the `name` column when searching for matches, since this doesn't appear in the sequence file.